# How should be the content of api.suite.yml Yii2 codeception config file?

Tags: yii2, codeception

I need to test my Yii2 project's APIs, using fixtures, so I would like to know how should I fill the file `api.suite.yml`

Answer (score 0):

For to know how to generate your initial Codeception api test structure in your project, take a Look at: https://codeception.com/for/yii

That is the content that I use in my `api.suite.yml`:

```yaml
actor: ApiTester
modules:
    enabled:
        - \api\tests\Helper\Api
        - REST:
            url: http://localhost/index-test.php
            depends: Yii2
        - Yii2:
            part: [orm, email, fixtures]
        - Asserts
```